# Should I write "commence working AT any level" or "commence working FROM any level"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, idiomatic-language

Is this sentence natural? If not, how can I correct it more natural?

> Although I have previous experience, I am also considering to **commence working at any level** to gain understanding of the field.

Does this sentence sound natural? I think it should be *commence working from any level*. Or if there is another expression, could somebody let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe the following might sound more natural.  It's a little more passive and implies a desire to better yourself and develop.

"Although I have previous experience, I would be happy to start at any level to further improve my understanding in this field."